# How do I write a video encoder for use with Air Native Extensions

Tags: apache-flex, dll, air, air-native-extension

I am an experienced Flex / Air developer (it's my day job) and have in the past played with C / C++ (at uni many years ago).
I want to encode a video from Air but this is proving difficult and slow. The next logical step is to do this with some sort of native extension.
What I want to do is pass PNGs as key frames to the native extension and then get a video out (don't care what sort of video, no sound, I just want to use it as a layer in Adobe Elements).

Where do I start? What language should I write the extension in? It needs to be a dll so I assume .net or something like that.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Native Extensions docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSb464b1207c184b14-70ccb6bd12937b4f2d6-7ffe.html). Most platforms only support C language (with exception of Android, which supports Java). Yes, it must be DLL but .net has nothing to do with it. DLL using Native Extensions must contain C (Java) API for interaction with ActionScript, and the rest of your implementation can contain C++ or asm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does this mean that I can't create my dll using c#? I have played with that a bit in the past and found it pretty easy to get along with. Are there any libraries that I would get for free that would make encoding a video easy?

Comment: As I understand it, dll must contain undecorated functions with C-export and predefined names - this makes easy for Flash runtime to load library and get function pointers from it. Since C# isn't mentioned in the docs, this means it's out.